# Question regarding connected $T_{3}$ space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I know that a connected $T_{3}$ space with more than one point is necessarily uncountable. The proof which I'm familiar with uses the fact a $T_{3}$ space is in particular a $T_{1}$ space. I'm wondering whether the claim remains true if you demand only that the space is regular but not necessarily that it is $T_{1}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about an indiscrete space with exactly two points?

Comment: By the way, you mean "A connected $T_3$ space with more than one point is uncountable".

Comment: Indeed to both comments, I'll correct the question.
The Trivial topology is a bit of a dull (albeit correct) example since it is only vacuously connected and vacuously regular. I would be happy to see another example with a topology which is not Trivial.

Comment: I only knew that connected Tychonoff spaces are uncountable. Could you provide me with a reference for the stronger result?

Comment: @StefanH. See [here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2001;task=show_msg;msg=0248.0001.0001). If I recall correctly, a connected Tychonoff space having at least two points has cardinality at least $c$.

Comment: @Stefan: A countable space is Lindelöf, and a regular Lindelöf space is normal.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks, I've already checked the link David posted, and saw that it uses a number of facts all of which I once learned about 1) A countable space is Lindelöf. 2) A regular Lindelöf space is paracompact. 3) A regular paracompact space is normal.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Thank you. So this says that a countable regular space is also completely regular.

Comment: @Stefan: You don’t need to introduce the complication of paracompactness, though: the proof that a regular, Lindelöf space is normal is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Okay, I will give it a try :-)

Comment: @Stefan: No, you don’t immediately get complete regularity, because that doesn’t follow from normality in the absence of $T_1$. What you get is that disjoint closed sets can be functionally separated.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: If I remember correctly a regular normal space is completely regular.

Comment: @Stefan: Not true: just take the indiscrete topology on any set with more than one element. Every $T_4$-space is Tikhonov, but you really need $T_1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: By completely regular I mean Tychonoff without $T_1$ ( point and closed set can be functionally separated). Isn't the indiscrete space $\{a,b\}$ then completely regular?

Comment: @Stefan: I know; that’s also how I use the term. My example was nonsense. In fact the argument that I gave in my answer actually shows that you **do** get complete regularity, though you have to work for it a little, since singletons need not be closed.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: No problem. But I'm still struggling with the regular Lindelöf implies normal. Maybe I'll get back to you if I don't succeed.

Comment: @Stefan: If you get stuck, take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403318/interesting-normality-condition-topology) and my answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott There was no conclusion to whether a normal space is necessarily completely regular or not. If the claim is true I'd appreciate a reference to a proof :)

Comment: @Serpahimz: The [Sierpiński space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) is vacuously normal, but it’s not completely regular: there is no continuous real-valued function separating the isolated point $1$ from the closed set $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The indiscrete (= trivial) topology is the only counterexample.

Let $X$ be a connected regular space, and suppose that $X$ is countable. Then $X$ is Lindelöf, and a regular Lindelöf space is normal (though not necessarily $T_1$). If $X$ contains two non-empty disjoint closed sets, Uryson’s lemma ensures the existence of a continuous surjection $f:X\to[0,1]$, showing that $|X|\ge 2^\omega$. Thus, $X$ cannot contain a pair of non-empty disjoint closed sets.

Suppose that $x\in X\setminus F$, where $F$ is a non-empty closed set; by regularity $x$ has an open nbhd $U$ such that $x\in U\subseteq\operatorname{cl}U\subseteq X\setminus F$. But then $\operatorname{cl}U$ and $F$ are non-empty disjoint closed sets, which is impossible. It follows that no non-empty proper subset of $X$ is closed and hence that no non-empty proper subset of $X$ is open. Thus, $X$ must have the indiscrete topology.

Comment: One thing I'm unsure of is why does Ursyohn's lemma ensure the existence of a surjection to $\left[0,1\right]$?
The formulation of the lemma I'm familiar with only ensures a continuous function separating the sets but nothing is said about it needing to be a surjection.

Comment: @Serpahimz: It gives you a continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(y)=0$ if $y\in\operatorname{cl}U$ and $f(y)=1$ if $y\in F$. Continuous maps preserve connectedness, so $f[X]$ must be a connected subset of $[0,1]$ containing both $0$ and $1$. There is only one such subset, $[0,1]$ itself, so $f$ must be a surjection.

Comment: Ah very nice. Thanks!

Comment: @Serpahimz: You’re welcome!