# Extending an homeomorphism to a $G_\delta$ set (comment on @Brian M. Scott's proof)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, descriptive-set-theory

This question has already been [posed and aswered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152680/extending-a-homeomorphism-of-a-subset-of-a-space-to-a-g-delta-set?r=SearchResults), but I think the proof proposed by @Brian M. Scott can be "simplified". If not, I would like to understand why.
**NOTE:** I ask this question because @Brian M. Scott seems to be no more active on this site, so I can't get an answer from him.

I want to prove the following:

> If $X$ is completely metrizable, and $A\subseteq X$ with $f:A\to A$ a homeomorphism, then there is a $G_\delta$ set $G\subseteq X$ containing $A$ and an extension $h:G\to G$ of $f$ which is a homeomorphism of $G$.

As I understand it, a proof goes as follows:

(1) there is (Lavrintiev's Theorem) an extension $f_0\colon G_0\to H_0$  where $G_0$, $H_0$ are $G_\delta$ containing $A$;

(2) Then, for every $n$, put $$f_{n+1}=f_n\upharpoonright (G_n\cap H_n)\colon G_n\cap H_n \to f_n(G_n\cap H_n)$$
 homeo and let $G_{n+1}=G_n\cap H_n$ and $H_{n+1}=f_n(G_n\cap H_n)$.

If I argue correctly, $G\colon =\bigcap_{n\in\omega} G_n=\bigcap_{n\in\omega} (G_n\cap H_n)$ is obviously $G_\delta$ and contains $A$; moreover, $h=\bigcap_{n\in\omega} f_n$ is a homeo which equals $f$ on $A$ and $$h(G)=\bigcap_{n\in\omega} f_n(G_n)=\bigcap_{n\in\omega} G_{n+1}=G.$$

What I miss is why in the [above answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152680/extending-a-homeomorphism-of-a-subset-of-a-space-to-a-g-delta-set?r=SearchResults) the construction involves a distinction between even and odd numbers.
Thank you in advance for you help.

Can someone give me a counterexample of why my attempt is wrong and the one be @Brian is correct, whenever it exists?

Comment: We take care of the inverse in the one half of the indices. In general we cannot assume $h$ is a homeomorphism on $\bigcap_n G_n$ to itself if we just consider the forward direction.

Comment: @Henno Your argument looks reasonable, but as I understand it, $f_n$ is a homeo at each step, $G_n$ is a monotone sequence and the restriction of homeo is a homeo. I apologize for what I'm not able to see.